# Making a pyramid using loops

Tags: python

I'm supposed to make a pyramid using loops. We have to make a pyramid using lines and dashes. We can come up with the pattern on our own, but it has to be lines and dashes. I got the line part working, but I have no idea how to get the dashes. My pyramid looks fine though.

What the pyramid is supposed to look like:

User inputs 3:

```
   -
  | |
  ---
 | | |
------
| | | |
-------
```

something like that. (as you can see there are 3 levels)

This is my code so far.

```
def pyramid():

    while True:
        try:
            height = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 1000: "))
            if 1<= height <=1000:
                for i in range(0,height):
                    print( ' '*(height-i-1) + '|'*(2*i+1))

            else:
                print ("Only numbers between 1 and 1000 are allowed.")

        except:
            print("Numbers between 1 and 1000 only.")


pyramid()
```

I'm guessing I need 2 loops, but how would I start it?

Comment: Why do you have the while loop? You go into infinite looping.

Comment: This code does not give you the output you posted.

Comment: @coldspeed I know, it makes a pyramid, but not the way I want it to.